# Double clicking the trackpad is suddenly hard

Tags: trackpad

My trackpad became tough to double click, i.e., I had to apply extra force to double click, while the force needed to single click remained the same. The MacBook is not damaged in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the computer solved the problem. I can now click as easily as I could earlier. Please comment if you know why this is happening or add an answer if you know of any other way to solve this.